# Is there a way to avoid multi click on SVG

Tags: animation, svg, click

If you animate an `<svg>` on click event `begin="item.click"` and the animation duration is for exemple 5 sec. If you click before the end of the animation, it becomes a big mess.

Is there a way to avoid click until the en of the animation ?

Here is [a pen I've done](http://codepen.io/alienlebarge/pen/QwObdR/). I you click several time, it's a mess !

Answer (score 0):

The [restart attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/animate.html#TimingAttributes) can be used to prevent an animation being restarted when it's running. Try restart="whenNotActive"